# Realm Swift - variable number of values in an object

Tags: ios, realm, swift4

In a situation where a random 'workout' might have any number of exercises from say, 5 - 20, is there a way to save a 'workout object' in Realm where there is a variable number of values (exercises)?

e.g. I currently have something like this as my object model:

```
@objc dynamic var workoutID = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var workoutName = ""
    @objc dynamic var totalExercisesCount = 0
    @objc dynamic var exerciseOne = ""
    @objc dynamic var repsExerciseOne = 0
    @objc dynamic var exerciseTwo = ""
    @objc dynamic var repsExerciseTwo = 0
    @objc dynamic var exerciseThree = ""
    @objc dynamic var repsExerciseThree = 0
    @objc dynamic var exerciseFour = ""
    @objc dynamic var repsExerciseFour = 0
    @objc dynamic var exerciseFive = ""
    @objc dynamic var repsExerciseFive = 0
    @objc dynamic var exerciseSix = ""
    @objc dynamic var repsExerciseSix = 0
```

This works fine but it also frequently populates many fields with 'null' (for example if there are only 3 exercises in a specific workout and 6 dynamic var's as per above).

It just feels like quite an inelegant solution but not sure if there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a `List` to store a dynamic number of variables attached to your workout session. You should create a `WorkoutExercise` class that contains the reps and name of the exercise and store a list of `WorkoutExercise`s in your `WorkoutSession` model.

```
class WorkoutExercise: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var reps = 0
}

class WorkoutSession: Object {
    @objc dynamic var workoutID = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var workoutName = ""
    let exercises = List<WorkoutExercise>()
    var totalExerciseCount: Int {
        return exercises.count
    }
}
```

I'd also recommend changing `totalExerciseCount` to a computed property (which will also make it ignored, since you can't store computed properties in Realm), since its value should always reflect the number of elements in `exercises` and there's no need to make it a persisted property, because you can always recompute it without a big computational cost.

Comment: just reading about lists now (i'm new to Realm) - this definitely makes sense and will achieve what I want thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. If you're new to Realm, I'd definitely recommend reading the [official docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/), since they contain all information needed for starting using Realm.

Comment: hi David - on this, because exercises is a "let" it's telling me I can't assign a property to it?  Should this be a var?

Comment: No, since `List` is a reference type, you can add values to it even it is declared immutable. And since `List` only has an empty initializer, it wouldn't make sense to declare it as mutable using `var`. You don't need to assign a value to `exercises`, you should simply add values to it using `append`.